# Why is the compiler confused into a SIGSEGV by unsigned int?

Tags: c, gcc, unsigned, segmentation-fault

I have distilled a problem I had which made me figure out what is happening, but still not exactly why.

```
int main() {
    unsigned int a = 2;
    char c[2] = {};
    char* p = &c[1];
    return p[1 - a];
}
```

It is a bit clearer when the last line is rewritten.

```
    return *(p + (1 - a));      /* equivalent */
    return *(p + 1 - a);        /* works */
    return *(p + (1 - (int)a)); /* works */
```

I'm surprised that the compiler doesn't remove the parenthesis internally. And more so that it apparently tries to hold a temporary negative result of type `unsigned int`. Unless that's not the reason for segmentation fault here. In the assembler output there is only little difference between code with and without parenthesis.

```
-   movl    $1, %eax
-   subl    -12(%rbp), %eax
-   movl    %eax, %edx
+   movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
+   movl    $1, %edx
+   subq    %rax, %rdx
```

Comment: `+` and `-` are left-associative , so `p + 1 - a` has to be processed as `(p + 1) - a`, which is of course different to `p + (1 - a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all about the C coercion rules. The expression `1-a` is treated as an `unsigned int`, and results in an underflow.  The compiler cannot remove the parentheses because you're mixing types. Consider your cases:

```
return *(p + (1 - a));      /* equivalent */
```

Calculates `1-a` first, but treats it as an `unsigned int`. This underflows the unsigned type, and returns the maximum value for an `unsigned int`. This is then added to the pointer, resulting in a dereferencing a pointer to something like `p+(1<<31)`, if `unsigned int` is 32-bit. This is not likely to be a valid memory location.

```
return *(p + 1 - a);        /* works */
```

This calculates `p+1` and then subtracts `a` from it, resulting in dereferencing `p-1`. This is technically undefined behavior, but will probably (in most implementations) reference a valid memory location on the stack.

```
return *(p + (1 - (int)a)); /* works */
```

This coerces `a` to a signed `int`, and then calculates `1-a`, which is `-1`. You then dereference `p-1`.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but what is the type of `1` initially? I understand that the result is cast into `unsigned int` because of `a`, but couldn't the result theoretically also adopt the type of `1` if it has any. Or is this just used as an instruction for *decrease `a` by 1 and flip the sign* basically.

Comment: @pdknsk The type of `1` is an `signed int`, but it's coerced to an `unsigned int`. See the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), section 6.3.1.8 (usual arithmetic conversions): "Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type."

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that in the expression `1 - a`, the `1` gets promoted to `unsigned int`, so you have `1U - 2U` which underflows to `UINT_MAX`. The take-home message here is that you always have to be *very* careful when mixing signed and unsigned ints in the same expression.

Not that a good compiler may warn you about such usages, provided you have warnings enabled of course:

```
main.c: In function 'int main()':
main.c:5:19: warning: '*((void*)& c +4294967296)' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     return p[1 - a];
```